# Basic Client Server Interaction in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React.js. I'm trying to set up a basic client/server interaction in which the server component generates a list of names and the client component displays them in a list.  I've cobbled together some code from online examples and tutorials. It compiles without error or warning. However, when I run it, the browser shows an error stating:

```html
×TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
```

Here's my client side component:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FetchUsers from "../controllers/FetchUsers.js";
class UserList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Users</h2>
                <FetchUsers users={this.props.pageContent.results} >
                    <div>
                      { this.props.pageContent.results.map(user => <p>{user}</p>) }
                    </div>
                </FetchUsers>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UserList;
```

Here's my server side code:

```html
export const FetchUsers = async () => {
    console.log('fetching user names');
    let results = [];
    results = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"];
    return { results };
}

export default FetchUsers;
```

How do I get the server side component to store some data in a way the client side can access and render it?

Comment: what are u using in backend?

Comment: You should create a state in your component, when componentDidMount - make a request, then on success change the state u've already set, and use this data in your render props function, just make a check if props.pageContent && props.pageContent.results && props.pageContent.results.length > 0